# What is meant by being "physically equal" in Haxe?

Tags: haxe, neko

I've been playing around with Neko Modules, but I think I'm getting some inconsistent behaviour.

```
var funcs = 0;
var objs = 0;
for (i in 0...m.globalsCount())
{
    var obj:Dynamic = m.getGlobal(i);

    if (Reflect.compareMethods(obj, init))
        trace("matched");

    if (Reflect.isFunction(obj))
        funcs++;
    else if (Reflect.isObject(obj))
        objs++;
}
trace('Functions: $funcs');
trace('Objects: $objs');
```

In the above code, when I run it the first time, I get a total of 4487 functions. If I remove a function, rebuild and run, I get the expected 4486.

I added the `compareMethods` comparison to compare the `obj` with `init`, where `init` is a function I declared in the Main file, but the trace is never output.

I glanced over at the code hint for the `compareMethods` function, and I stumbled across the following terminology: `if 'f1' and the 'f2' are **physically** equal`.

Now, they are both functions, and no where in the Haxe manual does it mention anything about physical functions. So I have a two part question, really.

What is a physical function, and how do I achieve the trace result as you would expect above? Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Dunno the answer to this, but I do wanna know what your objective is in the code snippet your posted above. Care to share?

Comment: I was hoping to use the method of calling functions from an external Neko module to allow for modifying existing applications without recompiling, effectively nullifying the need for ndll/dll files which I believe are strictly for native targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to haxe unit tests (and js source of Reflect) `Reflect.compareMethods` returns `true` only if you are comparing any method of the same object to itself.

```
// https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/ff3d7fe6911ab84c370b1334d537a768a55cca56/tests/unit/src/unit/TestReflect.hx
// 
// t(expr) - expr should be true 
// f(expr) - expr should be false 

function testCompareMethods() {
    var a = new MyClass(0);
    var b = new MyClass(1);
    t( Reflect.compareMethods(a.add,a.add) );
    f( Reflect.compareMethods(a.add,b.add) );
    f( Reflect.compareMethods(a.add,a.get) );
    f( Reflect.compareMethods(a.add,null) );
    f( Reflect.compareMethods(null, a.add) );
    /*
        Comparison between a method and a closure :
        Not widely supported atm to justify officiel support
        var fadd : Dynamic = Reflect.field(a, "add");
        var fget : Dynamic = Reflect.field(a, "get");
        t( Reflect.compareMethods(fadd, fadd) );
        t( Reflect.compareMethods(a.add, fadd) );
        t( Reflect.compareMethods(fadd, a.add) );
        f( Reflect.compareMethods(fadd, fget) );
        f( Reflect.compareMethods(fadd, a.get) );
        f( Reflect.compareMethods(fadd, null) );
    */
}
```

Also, possible use case

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a = new A();
        var i:I = a;
        trace(Reflect.compareMethods(a.test, i.test)); //returns true
    }
}

interface I
{
    function test():Void;
}

class A implements I
{
    public function new() {}
    public function test() {}
}
```